# Replace several regex groups with sed

Tags: sed, regular-expression

I want to add one blank space after any occurrence of:

```
<span class="negrita">ANYTHING</span>
```

So, with this SED instruction:

```
sed -E "s/(<span class=\"negrita\">.*?<\/span>)/\1 /g" <<< 'In <span class="negrita">1959</span> economic policy was reoriented in order to undertake <span class="negrita">the country modernization</span>. More text'
```

I get this output:

```
In <span class="negrita">1959</span> economic policy was reoriented in order to undertake <span class="negrita">the country modernization</span> . More text
```

So, as you can see, it is adding the blank space after the last occurrence, but not after the first one. Isn't the "/g" option meant to indicate that it should replace all occurrences?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The '.*' is a greedy match, matching _everything_ between the first match of '<span class"negrita">' and the last match of the closing '</span>'

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103149/non-greedy-reluctant-regex-matching-in-sed

Comment: sed in not a tool to parse HTML nor XML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`*?` is not a standard extended regular expression operator.

Depending on the `sed` or regexp engine implementation, it will either

1. report an error like on BSDs
2. be the same as `.*` (as it's like `(.*)?`) like on GNU systems
3. work like `perl`'s `*?` non-greedy version of `*` like with ast-open `sed`
4. do anything or everything as it's not a standard operator

You seem to be wanting `3`, but you're getting `2`, probably because your `sed` is GNU `sed`.

Note that `-E` is not a standard `sed` option either (though will likely be in the next major version of the POSIX specification).

If you want to use `perl` regexp operators, you should use `perl`:

```
perl -pe 's:<span class="negrita">.*?</span>:$& :g'
```

(that assumes *span*s don't nest and are not split on several lines)

Or with `sed`, you could do (assuming the contents of the span doesn't contain any `<`):

```
sed 's:<span class="negrita">[^<]*</span>:& :g'
```

Answer (score 2):

try

```
sed -E "s/(<span class=\"negrita\">[^<]*?<\/span>)/\1 /g"
```

where

- `[^<]` means any char but `<`

using your sample (with added `===`)

```
sed -E "s/(<span class=\"negrita\">[^<]*?<\/span>)/\1=== /g"
```

gives (folded manualy)

```
In <span class="negrita">1959</span>===  economic policy 
was reoriented in order to undertake <span class="negrita">the 
country modernization</span>=== . More text
```